# How to change initial language of flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I am trying to create Arabic flutter app and the default language of flutter app is English , I want the app to start with Arabic language , So how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en'),
        const Locale('ar'),
      ],
      locale: const Locale('ar'),
);
```